# Why do von Neumann algebras possess identity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, banach-algebras, duality

My starting point is that a von Neumann algebra is a $C^*$-algebra with a predual. The usual approaches to showing the existence of identity involve spectral theory (for approximate identity), but that seems to cloud away why the identity exists.

The reason I have in mind: If $\mathcal{A}$ is a von Neumann algebra with a predual $\mathcal{A}_*$, the lattice of invariant subspaces of $\mathcal{A}_*$ is isomorphic to the lattice of projections of $\mathcal{A}$. So the identity must be related to the whole predual. But this already involves lots of use of identity when describing weak$^*$-closed two sided ideals in terms of projections. So, it becomes a bit circular to use it.

I want to prove it purely using $C^*$-algebra structure and conjugate dualities between the following spaces:

[image]

I was trying to prove the existence of identity via second conjugate space, and Arens products.
The Arens products are defined by (then taking limits twice using Goldstine, Krein-Smulian, etc.),
\begin{align*}
    \big\langle \varphi |X\rtimes Y\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*}&\equiv \big\langle \varphi X |Y\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*},\\
    \big\langle \varphi |X\ltimes Y\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*}&\equiv \big\langle Y\varphi |X\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*}.
\end{align*}

The second conjugate gets two Banach$^*$-algebra structure (after some Goldstines and Krein-Smulians, and Alaoglu if necessary), and they two are equivalent for $C^*$-algebras.
\begin{align*}
    \big\langle \varphi| X\rtimes Y\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*} =\lim_{\beta}\lim_{\alpha}\Big[\big\langle B_\beta A_\alpha|\varphi\big\rangle_\mathcal{A}\Big],\\
    \big\langle \varphi| X\ltimes Y\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*} =\lim_{\alpha}\lim_{\beta}\Big[\big\langle B_\beta A_\alpha|\varphi\big\rangle_\mathcal{A}\Big].
\end{align*}
Heuristically, the conjugate space $\mathcal{A}^*$ lends its two sides to carry the product over to the second conjugate $\mathcal{A}^{**}$. In presence of an identity element in $\mathcal{A}^{**}$, the righthand side of the pairing can completely let go of the elements to the other-side, and "hold" on the the identity. This allows for the exchange of $X$ and $Y$s and we must have,
$$\big\langle \varphi |X\rtimes Y\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*}=\big\langle Y\varphi X|1\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*}=\big\langle \varphi |X\rtimes 1\ltimes Y\big\rangle_{\mathcal{A}^*}.$$

But how can I make sense of this heuristics? I am trying to approach via universal property as follows; Consider the identity map on the von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Since this is a map to a von Neumann algebra, it must pass through the second conjugate (since it is the universal enveloping von Neumann algebra).

[image]

Hence there must exist a map $I_\mathcal{A}$ such that $I_\mathcal{A}\circ \iota_\mathcal{A}=1$, and if $E_\mathcal{A}\equiv \iota_\mathcal{A}\circ I_{\mathcal{A}}$ then we have, $(\iota_\mathcal{A}\circ I_{\mathcal{A}})^2=\iota_\mathcal{A}\circ I_{\mathcal{A}}$ which is a projection map "on" $\mathcal{A}^{**}$. I want to show that $E_\mathcal{A}$ is actually "in" the envelope. So that I would have then showed that the identity map "on" the von Neumann algebra must also be "in" the von Neumann algebra.

Not much tools available other than these. I am allowed to use the $C^*$-structure of course. But no spectral theory or approximate identities (directly), mainly because the more "theory" there is in between, more clouded the reason why some phenomenon is happening (to me). Just conjugate pairings, duality, and $C^*$-structure.

I know I should show that $E_\mathcal{A}$ is a continuous functional on $\mathcal{A}^*$. But I was wondering how?